# Map Fragment loops back to current location after searching a new place in SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: java, android, supportmapfragment, placeautocompletefragment

I have added a Support Place Autocomplete fragment inside a Map Fragment, and it does not seem to work properly for some reason. Whenever I search for a place, the map moves to the correct location for a split second, and automatically  returns back to the user's current location for some reason.

This is the code of my map fragment:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment mPlaceAutocompleteFragment;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,
            container, false);

    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    layout.addView(v, 0);

    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.place_autocomplete, new SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment())
            .addToBackStack(SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.class.getName())
            .commit();


    mFusedLocationClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);

    if (childFragment instanceof SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) {
        ((SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) childFragment).setOnPlaceSelectedListener(
                new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                        LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Status status) {
                    }
                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mGoogleMap == null) {
        getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }
}


@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setPadding(0,200, 0,0);

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(120000); // two minute interval
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(120000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
        if (locationList.size() > 0) {
            //The last location in the list is the newest
            Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
            Log.i("MapsActivity", "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            //Place current location marker
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");


            //move map camera
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));
        }
    }
};

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel the problem is with your LocationCallback

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking, but cant seem to find a solution

Comment: You can remove location callback right after you get your location once, like you did it in `onPause()` and you would not get the updates of location, and start to get it when you need.

Comment: I have tried to removelocationupdates with FusedLocationClient, but it does not seem to work.